# Assigning by reference an array returned by a method call in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment

I need to loop on each `$message` recipient (recipients is an `array`) and, if something goes wrong, `unset` the corresponding recipient:

```
$recipients = &$message->getRecipients(); // array

// Do this now as arrays is going to be altered in the loop
$count = count($recipients);         

for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++):

    $response = $messageManager->send($recipients[$i], $content);

    // If not 200 OK remove the recipient from the message
    if($response->getStatusCode !== 200) unset($recipients[$i]); 

endfor;
```

But PHP won't let me do this, as "only variables can be assigned by reference". Is there something i can do, apart from re-assigning the array:

```
$recipients = $message->getRecipients();

// Loop

$message->setRecipients($recipients);
```

**EDIT**: can't use foreach and pass the current element by reference:

```
$recipients = array('a', 'b', 'c');

foreach($recipients as &$recipient)
    unset($recipient);

echo count($recipients); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead :

```
$recipients = $message->getRecipients();      

foreach($recipients as $key => $recipient) :

    $response = $messageManager->send($recipient, $content);
    if($response->getStatusCode !== 200) unset($recipients[$key]); 

endforeach;

$message->setRecipients($recipients);
```

Comment: note the & before $recipient, it will pass it by reference and not copy

Comment: Current element is passed by reference, the whole array is copied. That is array is not modified. Just tested...

Comment: Did you try it and it does not work ? because I do this all the time